# XPages: where to get detailed documentation

Tags: xpages

This is not a technical question, but rather an inquiry on how to get better information regarding the huge numbr of parameters and properties of the various controls you can put in an XPage.

A concrete example:

I have a button which had a property save=true in its event Handler.  I added some code in the postSave event, so a lotuscript angent could do some processing, and I started having save conflicts.  It took a while but I managed to figure out that the save=true in the event Handler was causing the issue.

I like to know my options, so I wanted to look at what exactly that property ws doing (although the name kinds of give it), but that's when it hit me: where do I look for that kind of information?

Is there a site somewhere that lists all properties we can add and a description of what they are doing?

Maybe my Google skills are not the best, but I couldn't find anything yet...

Comment: I don't know of any comprehensive documentation.  You're issue I assume were that you had 2 saves going on.  1 in XPages and the other in LotusScript.  The best thing you can do to move forward in XPages is to abandon using LotusScript like that.  Re-do that LotusScript code as a SSJS or Java Function. Also consider limiting your use of @functions from inside XPages....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be useful:
http://xpageswiki.com/
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_cref.html

Howard

Comment: That helps for sure, but it's too bad they don't explain a bit more what each property does...  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

The three IBM Press XPages books (Mastering XPages 2nd Edition, XPages Portable Command Guide and XPages Extension Library) are key to understanding the implications of the properties. There are the equivalent of Javadocs for controls (here's the link for the XPages Extension Library one), but they're not intended to go into the kind of depth to identify the problem you hit.

Comment: Paul, I already have these 3 books.  Of course I didn't go through all of them completly, but I would like something a bit more "complete" to look at, when needed.  The more apps I'll do with XPages, the more questions like this I'll have I guess...